# Aligning two collumns in a different way

Tags: multicol, typewriter

I have to print a multiple sequence alignment, which means I have to use monospaced font and two collums to achieve good alignment on a text which looks like this one:
`gi|161129|gb|AAA29941.1|          MSGSRKFFVGGNWKMNGSRDDNDKLLKLLSEAHFDDNTEVLIAPPSVFLH
gi|29841157|gb|AAP06170.1|        MSGSRKFFVGGNWKMNGSRDDNDKLLKLLSEAHFDDNTEVLIAPPSVFLH
gi|146741274|dbj|BAF62292.1|      MSGSRTFFVGGNWKMNGSREDNEKLLKLLSEAHFGDNTEVLIAPPSVFLH
gi|71983330|gb|AAZ57433.1|        MSGSRKFFVGGNWKMNGSQEENKKLLHILSDAHFGDNTEVLIAPPFVFLQ
gi|480328213|gb|AGJ83762.1|       MASNRKFFVGGNWKMNGSKESNQKLLKTLSDAKPDANTEILVAVPFVYLK
gi|358332321|dbj|GAA50994.1|      MEHNRKFFVGGNWKMNGSQSEIDKLIKMLSKAQLDPNTDVLVAPPVLYLQ
gi|167643879|gb|ABZ90134.1|       MSNQRKFFVGGNWKMNGDKDELTKICNSLMNAKLHETTEVVVAPPSIYLD
gi|565321260|gb|ETE72092.1|       -MAPRKFFVGGNWKMNGDKKSLSELIHTLNEAKVPAETEVVCGAPSIYLD
gi|568249377|gb|ETN59184.1|       --MGRKFCVGGNWKMNGDKASIAELCKTLSAGPLDPNTEVVVGCPAPYLS
gi|3184376|gb|AAC39072.1|         --MSRKFCVGGNWKMNGDQKSIAEIAKTLSSAALDPNTEVVIGCPAIYLM
                                      *.* *********.: .  :: : *  .     *::: . *  :*`

I'm having the worst time trying to do this by combining multicol and texttt, because I have to add several instances of this, which will occupy several pages. Ajusting it manually seems absurd, since the two colums break the text at the end of the page automatically. Maybe I should try using tables? Or Should I only take a screenshot of the already aligned sequence and insert the image on the document?

Comment: try with `longtable` package

Comment: if the part on the right side of a line is associated with the part on the left side, you could use `tabular`, with the left part left-aligned and a "tab" to a "tab stop" at the end of the line for the right part..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution

**Edit** just for example use `\usepackage[scale=.9]{geometry}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scale=.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{>{\ttfamily}l>{\ttfamily}r}
gi|161129|gb|AAA29941.1|       &   MSGSRKFFVGGNWKMNGSRDDNDKLLKLLSEAHFDDNTEVLIAPPSVFLH\\
gi|29841157|gb|AAP06170.1|     &   MSGSRKFFVGGNWKMNGSRDDNDKLLKLLSEAHFDDNTEVLIAPPSVFLH\\
gi|146741274|dbj|BAF62292.1|   &   MSGSRTFFVGGNWKMNGSREDNEKLLKLLSEAHFGDNTEVLIAPPSVFLH\\
gi|71983330|gb|AAZ57433.1|     &   MSGSRKFFVGGNWKMNGSQEENKKLLHILSDAHFGDNTEVLIAPPFVFLQ\\
gi|480328213|gb|AGJ83762.1|    &   MASNRKFFVGGNWKMNGSKESNQKLLKTLSDAKPDANTEILVAVPFVYLK\\
gi|358332321|dbj|GAA50994.1|   &   MEHNRKFFVGGNWKMNGSQSEIDKLIKMLSKAQLDPNTDVLVAPPVLYLQ\\
gi|167643879|gb|ABZ90134.1|    &   MSNQRKFFVGGNWKMNGDKDELTKICNSLMNAKLHETTEVVVAPPSIYLD\\
gi|565321260|gb|ETE72092.1|    &   -MAPRKFFVGGNWKMNGDKKSLSELIHTLNEAKVPAETEVVCGAPSIYLD\\
gi|568249377|gb|ETN59184.1|    &   --MGRKFCVGGNWKMNGDKASIAELCKTLSAGPLDPNTEVVVGCPAPYLS\\
gi|3184376|gb|AAC39072.1|      &   --MSRKFCVGGNWKMNGDQKSIAEIAKTLSSAALDPNTEVVIGCPAIYLM\\
            &            *.* *********.: .  :: : *  .     *::: . *  :*\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One last question, does this package react well to \centering? It's causing some nasty overfulls and some early tests aren't quite good.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, do you want (try) `\begin{longtable}{>{\ttfamily}c>{\ttfamily}c}`?

Comment: The text is long enough to cause overfull hbox, but it could fit well if the table were centered on the page. Now I see that \centering has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I understand now. by default longtable is centered, here the width of table is large, larger than textwidth. so you need to use \small befor the table and reset font size to normal after or change page layout make textwidth bigger

Comment: @BrunoYamada i update my answer